# Electric Power in Frequency Domain

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, fourier, circuit-theory

Let's consider an impedance Z inside a certain circuit. Let's suppose that we are working with a generic non periodic signal (so it is possible to analyze the circuit with the Fourier Transform).

How can we calculate the complex electric power absorbed by Z? If the signal is purely sinusoidal, we work with phasors and we write:

P = V × I*,

Where V is the voltage across Z and I is the current flowing on it.

But what if we are not in AC, but with generic signals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any voltage signal that is connected to some impedance Z, there is a resulting current. The voltage may be arbitrary and even the impedance can be arbitrarily changing but the same rule applies for calculating power: -

**Power equals voltage multiplied by current**

And, in this case, the voltage and currents are instantaneous values rather than RMS values. This is the bottom line for power measurement when you can't use sine waves (or regular cyclic signals) and the load might be varying.

So, instantaneous power values (calculated from instantaneous voltage and instantaneous current values) are averaged to produce average power and, it is average power that is important (especially so because power companies bill you on average power consumption, amongst other things).

Comment: And if we want to evaluate the average power in frequency domain? So by using V(f), I(f), Z(f)

Comment: Then you need to multiply exactly as you do with phasors but for each individual coherent frequency of relevance.

Comment: Are you done with this or do you need more clarification @Kinka-Byo

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much

Comment: Excuse me, I have another question about this topic. What if I want to find the whole power of an impedance Z(f) of a non-periodic signal (so whose spectrum is a continuous function of f)?